# How do I focus a modal WPF Window when the main application window is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have my MainApplication Window that launches a new Window with .ShowDialog() so that it is modal.

```
UploadWindow uploadWindow = new UploadWindow();
uploadWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Now users are often leaving this window open and it can get lost under other windows. When the MainApplication is clicked you get an error-like beep and are unable to interact with it, so the modal window is blocking properly as expected, but it would be nice if the modal window was focused at this point to show the user it was still open.

Currently it just looks as if the MainApplication window has locked up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try setting the dialog's owner:

```
var uploadWindow = new UploadWindow();
uploadWindow.Owner = this;
uploadWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I find it a little odd that the Owner property is not set by default. Thanks for the tip though, could turn out useful someday.

Comment: ← This. Seriously, what do you mean by `this`?

Comment: @ColonelPanic yep, `this` only works inside a window, not a UserControl or something else. `Window.GetWindow(this)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have the problem, that I can't use this, if someone have the same problem, you can use

```
Window.GetWindow(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using MVVM, I'm not creating the code from the GUI.  I used this.

```
var uploadWindow = new UploadWindow();
uploadWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
uploadWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above solutions tried and still facing the same problem
then here is your tested and verified solution
go to your window xaml and add

ResizeMode = "NoResize"

Comment: Does that cause the underlying modal dialog to become focussed?

Comment: Yes i was facing the same issue tried above all suggestions but couldn't worked for me then simply changed ResizeMode and objForm.ShowDialog(); worked

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can just set `Topmost = true`

```
var uploadWindow = new UploadWindow();
uploadWindow.Topmost = true;
```