# WPF: Dialog shows *under* the main window. How to get it to rise to the top?

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I use this code to produce a print-preview window.

```
using (XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.Read))
{
    FixedDocumentSequence fds = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

    using (var reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xaml)))
    {
        Window preview = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(reader) as Window;

        DocumentViewer dv1 = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(preview, "dv1") as DocumentViewer;
        dv1.Document = fds as IDocumentPaginatorSource;
        dv1.FitToMaxPagesAcross(1);

        // show the dialog
        preview.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

But the preview window typically shows beneath the main Window.  How can I get the preview to remain on top?

This code dynamically generates a Window from a simple XAML template at runtime, but that particular aspect of the code shouldn't be relevant to the problem I'm having.

---

> Duplicate:
>   [How do I focus a modal WPF Window when the main application window is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000588)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property of the `preview` window to the current window before showing the dialog.

```
preview.Owner = // the current window
preview.ShowDialog();
```